# Grayscale image filter

Tags: java, image, matrix, rgb, bufferedimage

I'm working on an image filter for grayscaling with a matrix and dividing the R+G+B colors by 3 in the follow loop as you see below.

```
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            Color c = inPixels[i][j];
            outPixels[i][j] = grayLevels[(c.getRed() + c.getGreen() + c.getBlue()) / 3];
        }
    }
```

But I've heard that doing it with intensity would be a lot better, so I tried something like this but it doesn't seem to work. My GUI application freezes when I'm trying to filter it like this. Perhaps anyone could help me out with this loop?

```
 for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) { 
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) { 
                short[][] intensity = computeIntensity(inPixels); 
                Color c = inPixels[i][j]; 

                outPixels[i][j] = grayLevels[(c.getRed() + c.getGreen() + c.getBlue()) / 3];
        }
```

If required I can post the other classes I'm working with but I don't think it's necessary since the code is pretty much self-explanatory.

Edit:
Here comes the intensity method:

```
protected short[][] computeIntensity(Color[][] pixels) {
    int height = pixels.length;
    int width = pixels[0].length;
    short[][] intensity = new short[height][width];
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            Color c = pixels[i][j];
            intensity[i][j] = (short) ((c.getRed() + c.getGreen() + c
                    .getBlue()) / 3);
        }
    }
    return intensity;
}
```

Thanks,
Michael.

Comment: Why are you recomputing the whole `intensity[][]` at each iteration of both loops? You are not even using the `intensity[][]` matrix, why?

Comment: I'm trying to have the intensity being used. I don't want it to calculate each pixel like it does right now.

Comment: The inside of grayLevels[] has to be made to work with the intensity term. That's my issue.

Comment: Can you provide the formula using intensity? When I was studying I followed a course on image processing, and the formula having the best result for human eye perception was `red * 0.299 + green * 0.587 + blue * 0.114`

Comment: You have just deported what you did in one method. So just do `outPixels[i][j] = grayLevels[intensity[i][j]];` but it changes nothing. Also, move the `short[][] intensity = computeIntensity(inPixels);` out of the two `for loops`

Comment: Ultimately, I don't want to create a new object for every new pixel. That seems to be a waste of resources and memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in the comments above, you may use a better equation to compute the grayscale : `red * 0.299 + green * 0.587 + blue * 0.114`.

```
protected Color[][] computeIntensity(Color[][] pixels) {
    int height = pixels.length;
    int width = pixels[0].length;
    Color[][] intensity = new Color[height][width];
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            Color c = pixels[i][j];
            intensity[i][j] = new Color(c.getRed() * 0.299, c.getGreen() * 0.587, c.getBlue() * 0.114);
        }
    }
    return intensity;
}

outPixels = computeIntensity(inPixels);
```

The `computeIntensity` is already computing the grayscales, so no need to re-iterate over all the pixels. You may even rename it to `computeGrayScales`